# How do I pass parameters from one ViewController to another?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5

How do I pass parameters from one ViewController to another ( I defined the ViewControllers in a storyboard)? Is there anything similar `putExtra` in Android, or any Bundle to put values?  I need to read some values from first ViewController and pass to another which is going to make POST request.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pass data between viewcontrollers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9659065/how-to-pass-data-between-viewcontrollers)

Answer (score 5):

`prepareForSegue:sender:` is the preferred way to pass data from one view controller to another when using storyboards.  Check the identifier to make sure it's the segue you're interested in, get a pointer to the destination view controller, and set whatever properties you want.  It might look like this:

```
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue*)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if( [[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"foo"] ) {
        FooViewController* fooView = segue.destinationViewController;
        fooView.someProperty = self.someProperty;
    }
}
```

The [Storyboard session from last year's WWDC](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/#introducing-interface-builder-storyboarding) is good watching, if you haven't seen it.

Answer (score 4):

this is very simple. You need to create a property(s) in the second viewcontroller, & pass the values to these propeties from the 1 viewcontroller

Comment: this is a very simple and fast way to do it, without (or even within) a storyboard app.

Answer (score 0):

apart from other ways, u can use Protocol and delegate for passing objects from one controller to another.
Lets say u need to pass object resposeData from controller (class) A to B, below are the steps that u can do:

1. Decalare a Protocol 
   eg.

   @protocol NetworkOperationDelegate

   @required

   -(void) operationCompleted:(id) responseData tag:(id) tag;

   -(void) operationFailed:(id) responseData tag:(id) tag;

   @end
2. Declare a property of type Id in class A, which points to ur delegate class

   `@property (nonatomic, retain) id < NetworkOperationDelegate > operationDelegate;`
3. lets say u initialise self.delegate in ur custom initiliser:

   -(id) initWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request operationDelegate:(id)   delegate tag:(id) tag

   ```
    {

    self = [super init];
     if (self) {
      self.request = request;
      self.tag = tag;
      self.operationDelegate = delegate;
    }
    return self;
   ```

   }
4. Then call the method on ur delegate whenever u want defined in class A: lets say when class A received the data, and u want class B to handle the data recieved
5. make sure to implement protocol method in class B
       @interface B : NSObject
       @end

   ```
   @implementation B

   -(void) operationCompleted:(id) responseData tag:(id) tag
   {

   // imlement code
   ```

   }

   -(void) operationFailed:(id) responseData tag:(id) tag
      {

   ```
    // imlement code
   ```

   }

   ```
   @end
   ```

Hope this helps!!!